# Add tag to existing data point in InfluxDB

Tags: influxdb

Is there a way to add a tag to an existing entry in InfluxDB measurement?  If not in the existing db measurement, is there a way to insert the records with a new tag into a new influx measurement?

Currently I have a set of measurements that should probably be entries in a single measurement where their current measurement names should be tag-keys in the superset of the merged measurements.

e.g.

```
show measurements
measurement1
measurement2
measurement3
measurement4
```

should instead be tags on the data included in each measurement and union to form a single measurement `joinedmeasurement` with indexed tags `measurment1`, `measurement2`,...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It would have to be done manually via queries.

For example, in python using the official client:

```
from influxdb import InfluxDBClient

client = InfluxDBClient('localhost', database='my_db')
measurement = 'measurement1'
db_data = client.query('select value from %s' % (measurement))
data_to_write = [{'measurement': 'joinedmeasurement',
                  'tags': ['measurement1'],
                  'time': d['time'],
                  'fields': {'value': d['value']},
                  }
                 for d in db_data.get_points()]
client.write_points(data_to_write)
```

And so on for the rest of the measurements. Can run the above in a loop to do all of them in one go.

Consider using named fields though in addition to tags. The above example only uses one field - can have as many as you want.

This improves performance further, though obviously fields are not indexed so do not use them for data that queries are to run on.

Comment: So essentially query all data in the db, append and then write to a new measurement.  That was always the backup plan, but was hoping to avoid this if possible.  Rightful punishment for poor schema design on my part up front.

Comment: I would really like to use this, but it throws on the write_points() 

File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\influxdb\line_protocol.py", line 145, in make_lines
    for tag_key, tag_value in sorted(iteritems(tags)):
  File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\six.py", line 587, in iteritems
    return iter(d.items(**kw))
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'items'